# How to expand a pack of character arrays into template parameters of character arrays and its index sequences?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-functions

I have following pseudo code that is trying to combine strings. Is there a way in C++ to expand a pack of `char` arrays(literal strings) into template parameter list of arrays and its index sequences?

```cpp
template <char const *S0, size_t... I0, char const *S1, size_t... I1, ...>
struct combine_t
{
    constexpr static char const val[] = {S0[I0]..., S1[I1]..., ..., 0};
};

template <size_t... L>
constexpr void combine_str(char const (&...strs)[L])
{
    constexpr char const *v = combine_t<((strs, std::make_index_sequence<L>), ...)>::val;
}
```

Comment: With that API, it's not possible. You cannot use the values of function parameters (*i.e.*, `strs` in `combine_str`) in contexts that require a constant expression (*e.g.* dereferencing them in order to initialize a `constexpr` variable, as you try to do inside `combine_t`). Once you pass something as a function parameter, you destroy its constant-expressionness. Would it be acceptable to you to have `strs` as template parameters instead?

Comment: Could you give usage example and output example? Why not just `char *str = "string1" "string2";` ?

Comment: If you use `std::array`, instead of C-array, [concatenating-a-sequence-of-stdarrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749032/concatenating-a-sequence-of-stdarrays) might help.

Comment: @BrianBi Would it be acceptable to you to have strs as template parameters instead?

Yes, that is fine as well. But then how do you get the length of the string literals without doing extra work?

Comment: @KamilCuk Why not just char *str = "string1" "string2"; ?

Because some of the strings passed to the `combine_str` function are returned by another constexpr function.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn your string literal into char sequences, and then "concatenate" them:

Following use gnu extension to transform literal sequence into char sequence, alternatively, you might use macro
[`MAKE_CHAR_SEQUENCE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733565/c11-constant-time-lookup-function-for-string-literals/22782915#22782915) to have similar result.

```
template <char ... Cs> struct char_sequence
{
    static constexpr const char data[] = {Cs..., 0};
};

// use gnu extension :/
template<class CharT, CharT... cs>
constexpr char_sequence<cs...> operator ""_seq(){
    return {};
}

template <char ... Cs1, char ... Cs2>
constexpr char_sequence<Cs1..., Cs2...>
operator+(char_sequence<Cs1...>, char_sequence<Cs2...>) { return {}; }
```

and then

```
template <typename ... CharSeqs>
struct combine_t
{
    constexpr static auto &val = (char_sequence<>{} + ... + CharSeqs{}).data;
};
```